Can jack post be cut?
I’m looking at the Mitek Redjacks to support beside a rotting support post. Only problem is the redjacks come in 92” and taller and I only have 78” clearance. Am I able to cut the red jacks down to the appropriate size or will it wreck the integrity of the post?

Why not buy one that fits? For example, there are jacks listed covering 54" to 150" at https://www.amazon.com/s?k=structural+column+jack, and one of 78" at https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=structural%2Bcolumn%2Bjack

According to the manufacturer:
Mitek redjack product page
“Square tube may be cut down, ensure cut is smooth, square and level.”
